# UIDocumentInteractionController not displaying app based on UTI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ibooks

I want to read .epub file in iBooks apps so I am using UIDocumentInteractionController to open.epub file in iBooks .Everything is working fin but I want to show only iBooks app instead of other apps in UIDocumentInteractionController so I added UTI for iBooks but still its display all the app below is my code.

```
 var sharingController = UIDocumentInteractionController()
  sharingController.url = url
  sharingController.uti = "com.apple.iBooks"
  sharingController.name = url.lastPathComponent
  sharingController.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.frame, in: view, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

UTI is not bundle identifier, but *uniform type identifier* of content.

Try the following

```
sharingController.uti = "org.idpf.epub-container"
```

or using constant from MobileCoreServices

```
import MobileCoreServices

...
sharingController.uti = kUTTypeElectronicPublication as String
```

**Update:** btw as provided above (and other) option do not limit the called option dialog as documented (see below), because it's determined all applications capable to *quick look, copy, open, etc* for the file

```
// This is the default method you should call to give your users the option to quick look, open, or copy the document.
// Presents a menu allowing the user to Quick Look, open, or copy the item specified by URL.
// This automatically determines the correct application or applications that can open the item at URL.
// Returns NO if the options menu contained no options and was not opened.
// Note that you must implement the delegate method documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: to get the Quick Look menu item.
open func presentOptionsMenu(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, animated: Bool) -> Bool
```

if you'd need to `open` only the content of menu would be more short, only to readers supported *epub*.

```
// Presents a menu allowing the user to open the document in another application.  The menu
// will contain all applications that can open the item at URL.
// Returns NO if there are no applications that can open the item at URL.
open func presentOpenInMenu(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, animated: Bool) -> Bool
```

Comment: Thanks for help.I tried with both your .uti but still appear all the app in UIDocumentInteractionController  instead of only iBooks.

Comment: @Rushabh, would you print & show example of `url` which pass in?

Comment: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/935F34BD-6A11-4593-B8F0-DFA08B2F6264/tmp/FreadOm.epub

Comment: I tried presentOpenInMenu options so its display app list which is supporting .epub file but is their any way only show iBooks application then others apps